# Displaying Spotify API recommendation results in a Vaadin Grid

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, spotify

I'm working on a Vaadin Spring Boot web application and using the Spotify API in my app. I am creating a page that a user can use to access the Recommendations endpoint of the Spotify API. The page has a form that the user must fill with whatever genre they want to search through and then fill in the specific audio features they want results to match with. Once the form is complete, a button is clicked to call an API method that takes the form data and creates a TrackSimplified[] array with the search results.

I wanted to know if it's possible to fill a grid (on the same page) with the search results whenever the user clicks the button.

Here is my code with a blank grid along with the form and other parts of the page:

```
package trackour.trackour.views.advancedsearch;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dialog.Dialog;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.formlayout.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.formlayout.FormLayout.ResponsiveStep;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H3;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Paragraph;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.Icon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PreserveOnRefresh;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.RouteAlias;

import jakarta.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import se.michaelthelin.spotify.model_objects.specification.TrackSimplified;
import trackour.trackour.model.CustomUserDetailsService;
import trackour.trackour.security.SecurityViewService;
import trackour.trackour.views.api.APIController;
import trackour.trackour.views.components.NavBar;
import trackour.trackour.views.components.responsive.MyBlockResponsiveLayout;

@Route("search/advanced")
@RouteAlias("search/advanced")
@PreserveOnRefresh
@PageTitle("Advanced Search | Trackour")
// Admins are users but also have the "admin" special role so pages that can be
// viewed by
// both users and admins should have the admin role specified as well
@PermitAll
public class AdvancedSearch extends MyBlockResponsiveLayout{
    
    @Autowired
    SecurityViewService securityViewHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
    
    public AdvancedSearch(SecurityViewService securityViewHandler,
    CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService) {

        NavBar navbar = new NavBar(customUserDetailsService, securityViewHandler);

        TextField genre = new TextField();
        genre.setLabel("Genre");
        genre.setHelperText("The genre you want to search in.");
        genre.setRequired(true);
        genre.setAllowedCharPattern("[a-z,]");

        TextField acousticness = new TextField();
        acousticness.setLabel("Acousticness");
        acousticness.setHelperText("The acousticness of the track as a value between 0.0 and 1.0." +
                                    " The higher the value, the higher the chance the track is acoustic.");
        acousticness.setRequired(true);
        acousticness.setAllowedCharPattern("[0-9.]");
        
        TextField danceability = new TextField();
        danceability.setLabel("Danceability");
        danceability.setHelperText("The danceability of the track as a value between 0.0 and 1.0." +
                                    " The danceability depends on factors like tempo and rhythm stability. Higher is better.");
        danceability.setRequired(true);
        danceability.setAllowedCharPattern("[0-9.]");

        TextField energy = new TextField();
        energy.setLabel("Energy");
        energy.setHelperText("The energy of the track as a value between 0.0 and 1.0. " +
                            " The energetic value of the track depends on factors like speed and loudness." +
                            " Fast and loud tracks feel more energetic than slow and quiet tracks.");
        energy.setRequired(true);
        energy.setAllowedCharPattern("[0-9.]");

        TextField instrumentalness = new TextField();
        instrumentalness.setLabel("Instrumentalness");
        instrumentalness.setHelperText("Get the instrumentalness of the track as a value between 0.0 and 1.0" +
                                        " The higher the value, the higher the chance the track contains vocals.");
        instrumentalness.setRequired(true);
        instrumentalness.setAllowedCharPattern("[0-9.]");

        ComboBox<String> key = new ComboBox<>();
        key.setLabel("Key");
        key.setAllowCustomValue(false);
        key.setItems("C", "C♯/D♭", "D", "D♯/E♭", "E", "F", "F♯/G♭", "G", "G♯/A♭", "A", "A♯/B♭", "B");
        key.setHelperText("The key the track is in.");
        key.setRequired(true);

        TextField loudness = new TextField();
        loudness.setLabel("Loudness");
        loudness.setHelperText("The average loudness of the track." + 
                                " These values have mostly a range between -60 and 0 decibels." +
                                " Input values as positive.");
        loudness.setRequired(true);
        loudness.setAllowedCharPattern("[0-9.]");

        ComboBox<String> mode = new ComboBox<>();
        mode.setLabel("Mode");
        mode.setAllowCustomValue(false);
        mode.setItems("Major", "Minor");
        mode.setHelperText("Mode indicates the modality of a track," + 
                            " the type of scale from which its melodic content is derived.");
        mode.setRequired(true);  

        TextField tempo = new TextField();
        tempo.setLabel("Tempo");
        tempo.setHelperText("The estimated tempo of the track in beats per minute." +
                            " Tempo is the speed or pace of a given piece, derived from the average beats duration.");
        tempo.setRequired(true);
        tempo.setAllowedCharPattern("[0-9.]");

        TextField timeSignature = new TextField();
        timeSignature.setLabel("Time Signature");
        timeSignature.setHelperText("The estimated overall time signature of the track." +
                                    " The time signature is the number of beats in a bar." +
                                    " A three quarters beat would be given as the value 3." +
                                    " Range Allowed: 3-7");
        timeSignature.setAllowedCharPattern("[3-7]");
        timeSignature.setRequired(true);

        TextField valence = new TextField();
        valence.setLabel("Valence");
        valence.setHelperText("The valence of the track as a value between 0.0 and 1.0." +
                                " A track with high valence sounds more positive (happy, cheerful, euphoric)" +
                                " than a track with a low valence value (sad, depressed, angry).");
        valence.setRequired(true);
        valence.setAllowedCharPattern("[0-9.]");

        Dialog errorMessage = new Dialog();
        VerticalLayout dialogLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        errorMessage.add(dialogLayout);
        errorMessage.setHeaderTitle("ERROR");
        
        Paragraph errorParagraph = new Paragraph();
        errorParagraph.setText("Input is invalid!");
        dialogLayout.add(errorParagraph);

        Button closeButton = new Button(new Icon("lumo", "cross"),
            (e) -> errorMessage.close());
        closeButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);
        errorMessage.getHeader().add(closeButton);

        Button searchButton = new Button("Search");
        searchButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        searchButton.addClickListener(event -> {
            
            if (Float.parseFloat(acousticness.getValue()) > 1.0) {
                errorMessage.open();
                acousticness.setInvalid(true);
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(danceability.getValue()) > 1.0) {
                errorMessage.open();
                danceability.setInvalid(true);
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(energy.getValue()) > 1.0) {
                errorMessage.open();
                energy.setInvalid(true);
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(instrumentalness.getValue()) > 1.0) {
                errorMessage.open();
                instrumentalness.setInvalid(true);
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(loudness.getValue()) > 60) {
                errorMessage.open();
                loudness.setInvalid(true);
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(tempo.getValue()) > 200) {
                errorMessage.open();
                tempo.setInvalid(true);
            }

            if (Integer.parseInt(timeSignature.getValue()) > 7) {
                errorMessage.open();
                timeSignature.setInvalid(true);
            }

            if (Float.parseFloat(valence.getValue()) > 1.0) {
                errorMessage.open();
                valence.setInvalid(true);
            }

            String genreValue = genre.getValue().toLowerCase();
            float acousticnessValue = Float.parseFloat(acousticness.getValue());
            float danceabilityValue = Float.parseFloat(danceability.getValue());
            float energyValue = Float.parseFloat(energy.getValue());
            float instrumentalnessValue = Float.parseFloat(instrumentalness.getValue());
            int keyValue;
            String keyLetter = key.getValue();
            switch (keyLetter) {
                case "C": keyValue = 0;
                    break;
                case "C♯/D♭": keyValue = 1;
                    break;
                case "D": keyValue = 2;
                    break;
                case "D♯/E♭": keyValue = 3;
                    break;
                case "E": keyValue = 4;
                    break;
                case "F": keyValue = 5;
                    break;
                case "F♯/G♭": keyValue = 6;
                    break;
                case "G": keyValue = 7;
                    break;
                case "G♯/A♭": keyValue = 8;
                    break;
                case "A": keyValue = 9;
                    break;
                case "A♯/B♭": keyValue = 10;
                    break;
                case "B": keyValue = 11;
                    break;
                default: keyValue = -1;
                    break;
            }

            float loudnessValue = -Float.parseFloat(loudness.getValue());
            int modeValue;
            if (mode.getValue() == "Major") {
                modeValue = 1;
            } else {
                modeValue = 0;
            }
            float tempoValue = Float.parseFloat(tempo.getValue());
            int timeSignatureValue = Integer.parseInt(timeSignature.getValue());
            float valenceValue = Float.parseFloat(valence.getValue());

            // APIController.getRecommendations() returns a TrackSimplified[] array
            TrackSimplified[] tracks = APIController.getRecommendations(genreValue, acousticnessValue, danceabilityValue, energyValue, instrumentalnessValue, keyValue, loudnessValue, modeValue, tempoValue, timeSignatureValue, valenceValue);

            // TESTING
            System.out.println(tracks[0].getName());
        });
        
        FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
        formLayout.add(genre, acousticness, danceability, energy, instrumentalness, key, 
                        loudness, mode, tempo, timeSignature, valence, searchButton);
        formLayout.setResponsiveSteps(
            new ResponsiveStep("0", 1),
            new ResponsiveStep("300px", 3)
        );
        formLayout.setHeight("400px");
        formLayout.setWidth("900px");

        Grid<TrackSimplified> resultsGrid = new Grid<>();
        resultsGrid.addColumn(TrackSimplified::getName).setHeader("Song");
        resultsGrid.addColumn(TrackSimplified::getArtists).setHeader("Artist");
        resultsGrid.setHeight("400px");
        resultsGrid.setWidth("900px");

        // main container contining cards area and button
        VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        Div placeHolderTextContainer = new Div();
        placeHolderTextContainer.add(new H3("Advanced Search"));

        HorizontalLayout main = new HorizontalLayout();
        main.add(formLayout, resultsGrid);

        verticalLayout.add(placeHolderTextContainer, main);
        verticalLayout.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        // Create a responsive navbar component
        // Add some content below the navbar
        navbar.setContent(verticalLayout);

        setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        // Add it to the view
        add(navbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your concrete problem? The answer to your question is "yes". Turning your array into an collection and then use `setItems` on the grid.